# Android Simple Adapter

Tags: java, android, simpleadapter

I am getting this error when I am trying to compile. This used to work when I was using sdk 23 but now that I have upgraded to 26 I cant get it to compile.

```
Error:(41, 13) error: cannot find symbol class SimpleAdapter
```

This is my code that goes and gets a list of contacts off a website and displays them in a list view.

```
public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {
private SimpleAdapter adpt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Contact>(), this);
    adpt.setStyle(R.layout.contact_list_item);
    ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_contacts);
```

The contact class is as follows this is what I cast the returned xml into once it gets returned.

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {

private String Name;
private String Phone;
private String Cell;
private String Email;
private String Address;
private String Work;

public Contact() {
    super();
}
public Contact(String name, String phone, String cell, String email, String address,String work) {
    super();
    this.Name = name;
    this.Phone = phone;
    this.Cell = cell;
    this.Email = email;
    this.Address = address;
    this.Work = work;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.Phone = phone;
}

public String getCell() {
    return Cell;
}

public void setCell(String cell) {
    this.Cell = cell;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.Email = email;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.Address = address;
}

public String getWork() {
    return Work;
}

public void setWork(String work) {
    this.Work = work;
}
```

}

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Where does the SimpleAdapter class come from?

Comment: In my old project I included a lib called android-support-v4.jar I have also included this into the new project but I dont think that this is the problem. SimpleAdapter was available in the old project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a SimpleAdapter, can extend from ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter,...

Comment: [https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). This is an example about **ArrayAdapter**

Comment: Yes I think I am going to have to do this